# Adding Colorbox to my ReactJS application creates "jQuery is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, colorbox

I'm trying to add [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) library to my project created with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app). I've installed `jquery-colorbox` package via npm and added imports in one of my *.js files:

```
import $ from 'jquery'; // also tried: import jQuery from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-colorbox';
```

After that, all I'm getting is an error:

> ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

```
 (anonymous function)
 node_modules/jquery-colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js:1105
  1102 | 
  1103 |    publicMethod.settings = defaults;
  1104 | 
> 1105 | }(jQuery, document, window));
  1106 | 
  1107 | 
  1108 |
```

Anyone have any suggestions how to manage with that problem?

Also, the code I want to run with the Colorbox library is something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.colorbox-group' + id).colorbox({
        rel: 'colorbox-group' + id,
        maxWidth: '95%',
        maxHeight: '95%'
    });
});
```

**UPDATE #1**

Also... tried with CDN's and added these lines to `index.html` file:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.colorbox/1.6.4/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
```

And run code inside one of JS files of my app: `$.colorbox('something');`.
Result:

> TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_jquery___default.a.colorbox is not a function

Comment: Have you tried my solution? Does that solve your issue?

Comment: @Upasana I promise I will check it as fast I can :). I'll let you know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1: Using cdn for jquery & jquery-colorbox**

[Here](https://github.com/upasanaa/react-jquery-colorbox) is a simple github repository, I have made using reactjs. Hope it helps!

**Solution 2: Using npm packages for jquery & jquery-colorbox**

[Here](https://github.com/upasanaa/react-jquery-colorbox-usingNPM) is a github repository using npm packages with react setup. I have also had the same issue that you got for 'jQuery' undefined. The solution is in webpack config by adding a webpack plugin for jQuery. Add this in your webpack-config file:
On top first import the webpack:

```
let webpack = require('webpack');
```

and then add this code:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery"
    })
]
```

**Solution 3: specifically for 'create-react-app'**

Update the import in your app.js file like below:

```
import jQuery from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = jQuery;
require('jquery-colorbox');
```

Hope it solves your query.

Comment: Sorry for the waiting. Nice and simple examples :). But the main big difference between your and my app, is I'm using create-react-app and I think that I don't have easy access to the `webpack.config.js` file. Is your way a better way to create React applications (to be honest, I'm not experienced in React, started this adventure with react-create-app package)?

Comment: Also, copied your App.js file and also having "jQuery" not defined :/. I think it somehow must be imported in the code. After importing with `import jQuery from 'jquery';` have "colorbox is not a function". I've added scripts into index.html.

Comment: Copying App.js file won't work unless you made changes in webpack config file. However I am looking into create-react-app just give me 10 mins.

Comment: @KrzysztofTrzos Got your issue. check the updated answer.

Comment: Could you also add example of `colorbox` variable usage, please? Is it still '$('.element').colorbox({ ... });`?

Comment: @KrzysztofTrzos yes it is same as previous nothing will be changed in usage. It is same as 'import' but just using 'requirejs'. I have checked the same example(used in my repo for npm packages) but using 'create-react-app' . It is working all fine.

Comment: @KrzysztofTrzos You could even remove the var colorbox and just do require('jquery-colorbox') it would work either way. In case of var colorbox it will show you a warning in console that it is never used as it is not used directly but via JQuery. I have updated the answer as well.

Comment: Oh man, it's working. Been trying to use "window.jQuery = jQuery;" but not "var colorbox = require('jquery-colorbox');". I've been trying to import `colorbox` before the line `window.jQuery = jQuery;` so that's why it wasn't working. The `require` solved the problem. Thanks for your all solutions! BTW. Could you tell me on chat is it better to create apps with "create-react-app" or with custom made webpack (like solution no #1 and #2)?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is using the variable *jQuery* rather than *$*.  I might try importing the jQuery object by its name, for example:

```
import {$, jQuery} from 'jquery';
```

or maybe just:

```
import jQuery from 'jquery';
```

Comment: Tried that, like I mentioned in the question. Doesn't work :(.